# How expose static symbol name and memory address in gcc memory map file without attribute?

Tags: c, gcc, overlay

As for a copy of a particular driver from a flash load address as a .driver_data section in to the overlay ram memory section, the static symbol as part of the driver data cannot be visible in the memory map file and for this reason cannot be referenced in the overlay compartment ram .
How can gcc make static symbol names and addresses visible in the memory map file and not be hidden behind the name of the object they are in?

Im try to locate symbol using -readelf but not get symbol names and section only address .

Comment: can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to explain exactly your problem?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, but here's a shot in the dark: are you missing a '-g' compiler option so that symbol names are included in compiled output?